# snd-hda-intel doesn't show up and no sound output from internal speakers

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, asus, hda-intel

I have an Asus ROG Strix g16 2023 model laptop and I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 with Kernel 6.6.8. There is no sound from my internal speakers. When I connect headphones or external speakers, I hear sound, but when I try without them, there is no sound at all.

Here's my lspci output:

```
0000:00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Device a72a (rev 01)
0000:00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device a70d (rev 01)
0000:00:02.0 Display controller: Intel Corporation Device a78b (rev 04)
0000:00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Device a71d (rev 01)
0000:00:08.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Device a74f (rev 01)
0000:00:0e.0 RAID bus controller: Intel Corporation Device a77f
0000:00:13.0 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Device 7a79 (rev 11)
0000:00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Device 7a60 (rev 11)
0000:00:14.2 RAM memory: Intel Corporation Device 7a27 (rev 11)
0000:00:14.3 Network controller: Intel Corporation Device 7a70 (rev 11)
0000:00:15.0 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Device 7a4c (rev 11)
0000:00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Device 7a68 (rev 11)
0000:00:1a.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 7a48 (rev 11)
0000:00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 7a3d (rev 11)
0000:00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 7a30 (rev 11)
0000:00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Device 7a0c (rev 11)
0000:00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Device 7a50 (rev 11)
0000:00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Device 7a23 (rev 11)
0000:00:1f.5 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Device 7a24 (rev 11)
0000:01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 2860 (rev a1)
0000:01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation Device 22bd (rev a1)
0000:02:00.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 1133 (rev 02)
0000:03:00.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 1133 (rev 02)
0000:03:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 1133 (rev 02)
0000:03:02.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 1133 (rev 02)
0000:03:03.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 1133 (rev 02)
0000:04:00.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Device 1134
0000:38:00.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Device 1135
0000:6c:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)
10000:e0:1d.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Device 09ab
10000:e0:1d.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 7a34 (rev 11)
10000:e1:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Micron Technology Inc Device 5413 (rev 03)
```